# Retag [calcite] to [apache-calcite]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Both the [calcite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/calcite) and [apache-calcite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-calcite) tags refer to the Apache Calcite. I'm specifically proposing that both be merged into [apache-calcite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-calcite) because in the past, several questions have also been tagged [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache), referring to the HTTP server which was unrelated to the question. Hopefully having `apache` in the tag name will deter this.